# Which url should be used for webhook

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using a custom Git platform(that's not GitLab, GitHub or BitBucket).

I want to integrate it with Jenkins such that every time I make a pull request, this will be built.

Therefore, I am trying to create a Webhook. When I'm adding the Webhook to the Git platform, it's asking me for a url where it will send a POST request.

I've given it the Jenkins' job url:

```
my-jenkins-server.com:8000/job/my-job
```

However, when I make a pull request, it isn't built.

So what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger the job with this URL:
`JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/build?token=TOKEN`

The token is only needed if you have specified a token for the remote API in your job.You can read more about the jenkins remote API [here.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

Comment: I sent a POST to this URL, where `token` is `API Token` from `JENKINS_URL/user/my-username/configure`. However, I'm getting a `404`.

Comment: Have you tried leaving th token out? The token is only set in the jobs configuration, not the user one. Alternatively you could try to use `JENKINS_URL/view/VIEW_NAME/job/JOBNAME` if your job is part of a view. To Add parameters then use `JENKINS_URL/view/VIEW_NAME/job/JOBNAME/buildWithParameters` and put the parameters in the POST body.